# Syntax Error:Invalid syntax when installing django in cent os 6.9

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error when executing this command "sudo pip install django"

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
 from pip._internal import main
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
from pip._internal import cmdoptions
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
from pip._internal.index import (
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 526
{str(c.version) for c in all_candidates},
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And python installed version is Python 2.7.11 using this command python -V

Comment: do `pip install --upgrade pip` and retry

Comment: It's running python2.6 (as evidenced by the folder) and the error originates from pip itself. I doubt it has anything to do with Django.

Comment: The immediate error is that Python 2.6 doesn't have set comprehensions. The top-level error is that you're using Python 2.6, and Django no longer supports Python 2.6, so you need to use 2.7 (or, better, 3.6 or 3.7).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.I have installed python 2.7.11 version,then how to switch over to use 2.7.11

Comment: If you have commands named `python2.7` and `pip2.7`, you can explicitly use those instead of `python` and `pip`. (If you just have the first, you can use `python2.7 -m pip` instead of `pip2.7`—or you can manually create a symlink/alias/whatever, but that's getting more toward something you should look for at SuperUser than here).

Comment: Hi @abarnert,shall i need to change env path to python2.7?

Comment: You probably don't need to change any PATH stuff, especially if the stuff I suggested in the last comment works for you. If you want something more convenient, the best answer is probably to use [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)`, or maybe to use [`anaconda`](https://www.anaconda.com/what-is-anaconda/) (a Python-with-extras distribution that includes its own separate package manager and virtual environment tool).

Comment: "/root/.local/bin/python2.7: No module named pip". I am getting this error after executing this command "python2.7 -m pip"